# Put a user ID which is later generated at the end of a link

Tags: code-generation, userid, roblox

Here is the code. I'm not sure if this would have to completely redone (this was given by a friend), I think I need something which would make it so after the "http://www.roblox.com/my/newmessage.aspx?recipientID=", I need it to be able to put in the user ID generated later in the script

This is the code: http://pastebin.com/T47B8Hy9
(I was having trouble putting the code into here)

Answer (score 0):

Please do **not** use such *spammers*, people WILL get *annoyed* and you might be **banned**. Make a nice Ad instead, or a recruitment place.

> It seems like the line
>
>       `$.post("http://www.roblox.com/My/NewMessage.aspx?RecipientID='.length",{`
> Should be replaced with
>
>      `$.post("http://www.roblox.com/My/NewMessage.aspx?RecipientID=" + userId,{`
>
>
> Can't test if it works with just that change, because of the nature of the script.